# facebook multiple publish to wall

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

im using the js sdk to post message to friends wall from my website through an app i created in facebook. the code above is going well when i post to single wall. the problem i want to post to multiple walls the same message at the same time and without popup or dialog appearing. i know it must be done by looping but cant get it working .

my code is

```
 var publish =
            {
                method: 'stream.publish',
                // display: 'popup',


                attachment: 
                {
                    name: 'name' ,
                    caption: 'www.caption.com'  ,
                    description: ('description'),
    href: 'url',
                    media: [
                  {
                    type: 'image',
           href: 'url',
                    src: 'url'
                  }
                ]                   
                }
            };

         publish.target_id =id1;
         FB.ui(publish);
         publish.target_id = id2;
         FB.ui(publish);

            return false;

        }
```

any kind of help will be apreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to: http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

```
5. You must not provide users with the option to publish more than one Stream story at a time.
```

You should avoid to post same message to multiple walls the same time.

**edit**:

But if you really wan't to do it:
You should not use Fb.ui(), that is used for Facebook Dialogs.

Instead you may use:

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

So, you just have to loop your UserIDs, and replace the "me" with the user_id.

Comment: It's worth noting that if Facebook's app team spot you doing this they will take your app down first and ask questions later, so consider if it is really worth it.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got it working using this code :

```
function  doitonfacebook(){

var receivers = document.getElementById("selected-friends").innerHTML; 

var temp = new Array();

temp = receivers.split(',');

var count =temp.length;

 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

 var publish = {

     method: 'stream.publish',
     message: 'test',
     picture : 'http://www.takwing.idv.hk/facebook/demoapp_jssdk/img/logo.gif',
     link : 'http://www.test.com',
     name: 'test',
     caption: 'Caption of the Post',
     description: 'testttttt',
     actions : { name : 'testing', link : 'http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/index.php'}
   };

FB.api('/'+temp[i]+'/feed', 'post',publish, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('success publishing: ' );
  }
});


        }}
```

thanks for the response